# Room Exception in an un-annotated class

Tags: android, android-room

I have an abstract class that I have two `@Dao` subclasses from:

```
public abstract class PathBase
{
    private static final String PATH_DELIMITER = "/";

    abstract PathEntity getPath(Long id);
    abstract Long insertInternal(PathEntity row);
    abstract String getDatabase();

    abstract List<Long> getAncestorsInternal(String path);
    abstract List<Long> getDescendantsInternal(String path);
    ...
}
```

As soon as this class is extended by an `@Dao`:

```
@Dao public abstract class FolderDao extends PathBase
```

I get this error:

> error: A DAO method can be annotated with only one of the following:Insert,Delete,Query,Update

for methods:

```
    abstract PathEntity getPath(Long id);
    abstract Long insertInternal(PathEntity row);
    abstract String getDatabase();
```

It does not complain about:

```
    abstract List<Long> getAncestorsInternal(String path);
    abstract List<Long> getDescendantsInternal(String path);
```

Even if it were tracing the `@Entity` class `PathEntity` I have no idea why it throws an error for `abstract String getDatabase();`.

Anyone have any idea what's going on here...Room bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, I get the error for all five of your methods, not just those first three, when I paste your `PathBase` into a project, swap in one of my entities for `PathEntity`, and have my DAO class extend `PathBase`.

These methods cannot be `abstract`. Room is generating the implementation of `FolderDao`, and Room has no way of implementing those methods. The specific error message is not ideal, but I can't see how this could ever work.

FWIW, I filed [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68140034) about the unclear error message.

Comment: <sigh> If the error had thrown on all five it would have saved me quite a bit of time.  Those methods are implemented in `FolderDao`, but I guess that still doesn't work (I'm new to magical annotations).  In hindsight, it shouldn't matter too much.  I initially started this design with a more object-oriented mindset, but that's hard with Room anyway.  A one-size-fits-all `Dao` to handle all relations makes as much sense as handling each `Entity` individually.  In which case all of the base code can be reused anyway.

Comment: @Anthony: "Those methods are implemented in FolderDao, but I guess that still doesn't work (I'm new to magical annotations)" -- I do not get that error when I add an implementation of `getPath()` to my DAO. What version of Room are you using? I am testing with `1.0.0-rc1`.

Comment: beta2, i'll try upgrading.

Comment: One of the subclasses used `long` not `Long` and was missing `getDatabase`.  The one I hadn't checked closely.  This model is obviously not going to work as it's too prone to ambiguous errors.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone encountering a similar situation with complex core query logic with 1.1.0 Room now allows `@RawQery` which allows you to cleanly implement core logic yourself.  Here's how I implemented this particular solution:

https://gist.github.com/rcketscientist/4ded9ae64a770ff6929f27b5dbdbe13a